# Reusing all my query strings when redirecting during pagination

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I have epxerimented with doing some pagination on my asp.net site.

The user can do some queries based on a lot of different constaints, and I have then used
`X.PagedList;` for this.

In order to go a new search page when a lot of entities have been read in, I have this PagedlistPager, where I grab all the needed query strings and use them again.

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("query", new
{
    page,
    Name = Context.Request.Query["Name"],
    Surname = Context.Request.Query["Surname"],
    Age = Context.Request.Query["Age"],
    From = Context.Request.Query["From"],
    To = Context.Request.Query["To"],
    sortBy = Context.Request.Query["sortBy"],
    ZipCode = Context.Request.Query["ZipCode"],
    Country = Context.Request.Query["Country"],

    
}))
```

This is quite tedious, is there any way that I can grab all my query strings and put them into the new GET request with the old query strings?

Comment: `put them into the new GET request with the old query strings` if there's an scenario that sometimes you don't want to put the old query strings into the new query? And does your requirement may lead to a result like `select * from table where column nm = 'old value' and column = 'new value' order by column desc(old query, but new query require no desc) `? In my humblm opinion, it's impossible. Did I misunderstand it?

Comment: yes, I want to take all the current query strings and give them to a new get request, so the same database calls can be made again. Using pagination, as described this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P-uxPyF9Icg&t=104s